# How can I figure out the source of a dll that is being added to /bin from msbuild?

Tags: jenkins, compilation, msbuild, mscorlib

I have a website that works locally. I've got a build task in Jenkins using msbuild to deploy it to my testing environment. The build works but it is adding the file mscorlib.dll to the /bin folder in my testing environment, and this dll is causing my site to not work. When I delete the dll my site loads. I cannot figure out where this dll is coming from. I searched in Visual Studio for mscorlib and there are no references to it in any of my projects, and when I build my project in Visual Studio that dll does not show up in my local bin folder. How can I figure out where this file is coming from, and stop it from being added?

Comment: Start by generating a binary log during the build that's putting the file there by adding the `/bl` argument to the MSBuild call and inspect it using the [MSBuild structured log viewer](http://msbuildlog.com). You could also upload this file provided you can share the project names and environment variables contained within that log.

Comment: If you cannot share this log, try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)